# Open the form based on the value acquired from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a form `dashboard.php` which displays different records (sampleid, type, user). There are two more forms named `aba.php` and `babab.php`. There is a button named Update in `dashboard.php` in front of each record.

When I click on that button it should open the perticular form based on the value of type. I tried the following code but this always open babab.php form.

What is wrong with my code?

```
<?php
   $type=$_GET['type'];

   if ($type =="WOOD") {
       $formid='aba-edit.php';} 
   elseif ($type=="BONE" OR 'CARBONATE' OR 'CELLULOSE'OR 'CHARCOL' OR 'CORAL'){
       $formid='babab-edit.php';}
   else {
       echo "Under Construction";}                                                 
?>

<a onclick="window.open('aba-view.php?sampleid=<?php echo htmlentities($result->sampleid);?>','_blank','height=700,width=1200 top=200 left=350,location=no,toolbar=no,resizable=0, scrollbars=no')">
<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i> VIEW</button>

<a onclick="window.open('<?php echo $formid ?> ?sampleid=<?php echo htmlentities($result->sampleid);?>','_blank','height=700,width=1200 top=200 left=350,location=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no, scrollbars=no')">
<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i> UPDATE</button>
```

Comment: Do you have an end tag of `</a>`?

Comment: inserted it after the </button>

Comment: try some checking error .. Try the `if ("WOOD" == "WOOD") { $formid = 'aba-edit.php'; }` and reply if what happen :D

Comment: what u mean by this  "wood"=="wood"

Comment: replace for checking the ` if ($type =="WOOD") { ...`

Comment: In this case it opens aba.php

Comment: and try `if ($_GET['type'] == "WOOD") { $formid = . . .`

Comment: still no joy in all case it is opening the form connected with elseif statement .It is not going to open the form connected with if statement.It is executingg the last statement

Comment: try to display the `$_GET['type']` .For example: `echo $_GET['type'];`

Comment: This value is already displayed in dashboard.php form in this list of all sample is displayed. and in front of every record there is this button

Comment: i tried it with  switch  but no joy                  <?php
           $type = $_GET['type'];
            switch($type){
             case "WOOD":
               $formid=aba.PHP;
               break;
             case "CORAL":
              $formid=babab.PHP;
              break;
            }
           ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $type =$result->type;
    if ($type ==WOOD or $type ==CELLULOSE ){
    $formid='babab-edit.php';
    } elseif($type==BONE){
    $formid='bone.php';
    }elseif($type==SEDIMENT OR $type==CHARCOL OR $type==PEAT){
    $formid='aba-edit.php';
    }else{
    $formid=nothing.php;
    }   
    ?>

   <a  onclick="window.open('aba-view.php?sampleid=<?php echo htmlentities($result->sampleid);?>','_blank','height=700,width=1200 top=200 left=350,location=no,toolbar=no,resizable=0, scrollbars=no')"><button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i> VIEW</button></a>
    <a  onclick="window.open('<?php echo $formid?> ?sampleid=<?php echo htmlentities($result->sampleid);?>','_blank','height=700,width=1200 top=200 left=350,location=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no, scrollbars=no')"><button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i> UPDATE</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yоu have error in the check syntax:

```
elseif($type=="BONE" OR 'CARBONATE' OR 'CELLULOSE'OR 'CHARCOL' OR 'CORAL'){
```

should be:

```
elseif($type=="BONE" OR $type=='CARBONATE' OR $type=='CELLULOSE'OR $type=='CHARCOL' OR $type=='CORAL'){
```

Comment: still opening the same page